# What could be the cause for GPS issues of variable length during specific time intervals (periodic gps problems)?

Tags: android, gps, locationlistener

I have developed an industrial geo-tracking application that runs daily. It uses GPS for long periods of time and requires accurate (GPS only) and frequent (~ every 5 sec) updates.

Although this app is running on multiple identical hardware models (Samsung Tab2), some devices do not report location updates for intervals of variable length (2 min up to 1 hour). (Curiously, this "blackout" period often happens around 15:00-19:00 GMT+2). Also, this tends to happen with just a subset of devices, suggesting a hardware problem.

Another possibility is that my processLocation method, called inside LocationListener.onLocationChanged takes too long and gets stuck (?). (Of course this doesn't explain why the problem is specific to a subset of devices for a certain period of time.)

This is a reproduction of that code:

```
mLocationListener = new LocationListener() {
 public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
  if (location.getProvider().equals("gps") && location.getAccuracy() < accuracyThresh) {
   processLocation(location, time);
  } else {
   discardLocation(location, time);
  } 
 }
 public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
 }
 public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
 }
};
```

The problem appears to fix itself after a blackout period.

This may be relevant ([What causes erratic GPS estimates during certain time intervals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15087738/what-causes-erratic-gps-estimates-during-certain-time-intervals)) although here there is nothing systematic about the time when this issues appeared.

As in that case, I am having difficulties to determine if this is caused by a bug in my code.

I wonder if someone has had a similar experience or could point me in the right direction. Any suggestions for debugging? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: all the devices are in the same place? or can you see a pattern between the location of the devices that do not report properly?

Comment: Yes, all the devices are in the same city but there isn't a geographic pattern behind these "blackout" periods.

Answer (score 0):

There are several factors that can influence the GPS accuracy. Before looking for bugs in your code I would suggest checking the following information:

[What factors influence GPS accuracy the most?](http://www.gps-basics.com/faq/q0121.shtml)

[Factors affecting GPS accuracy](http://precisiontracking.com.au/blog/factors-affecting-gps-accuracy/)

Comment: Thanks for the links Julian. Even though the problems described in them may be affecting our devices they doesn't explain why this issue seems to appear in a subset of devices without any specific correlation with their actual location.