# distanceTo() erratic results

Tags: android

I have a simple app that starts a gps method to get longitude and latitude to measure distance using Location and the result is added to a total distance variable to give the total journey.

But the total journey is erratic ranging from 0m to 6000m randomly during the run.

This is my code.

```
   public void geoloc_start() {

    // Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
    loc_man = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    // Define a listener that responds to location updates
    loc_list = new LocationListener() {

        // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
        public void onLocationChanged(Location geo_loc) {

            newLongitude = geo_loc.getLongitude();
            newLatitude = geo_loc.getLatitude();

            Location new_location = new Location("Point A");

            new_location.setLatitude(newLatitude);
            new_location.setLongitude(newLongitude);

            Location old_location = new Location("Point B");

            old_location.setLatitude(oldLatitude);
            old_location.setLongitude(oldLongitude);

            distance = old_location.distanceTo(new_location);
            tot_distance += distance;

            oldLatitude = newLatitude;
            oldLongitude = newLongitude;

    //************************ Round coordinates to 5 dec places + set them to string to display ************************//
            newLongitude = Math.round(newLongitude * 100000);
            newLatitude = Math.round(newLatitude * 100000);
            tot_distance = Math.round(distance * 1000);

            newLatitude = newLatitude / 100000;
            newLongitude = newLongitude / 100000;
            tot_distance = tot_distance / 1000;

            latitude_text = Double.valueOf(newLatitude).toString();
            longitude_text = Double.valueOf(newLongitude).toString();
            distance_text = Double.valueOf(tot_distance).toString();
    //*******************************************************************************************************************//

            geoLat.setText("Lat:  " + latitude_text);
            geoLong.setText("Long: " + longitude_text);
            geoDist.setText("Dist: " + distance_text + "m");
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }
    };

    // Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }

    loc_man.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 0, loc_list);
}

/*******************************************  STOP GPS FUNCTION *******************************************/
private void geoloc_stop() {

    loc_man.removeUpdates(loc_list);
    loc_man = null;

    geoLat.setText("Lat:  0");
    geoLong.setText("Long: 0");
    geoDist.setText("Dist: 0m");
    tot_distance = 0;
}
```

Comment: [Possibly related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15087738/what-causes-erratic-gps-estimates-during-certain-time-intervals).

Comment: What is troubling me is how the tot_distance is not adding up, if I have erratic measurments with distanceTo() at least the tot_distance should be adding up and not giving me random values example: 10.23 > 8.5 > 20.98 > 0.....

Comment: Are you using a real device to get those coords? Can you try another device?

Comment: I used an emulator with a GPX file loaded from another app, and I tried a real device, sometimes the app starts with a random distance by standing still outside

Comment: Have you tried `Math.abs(location.distanceTo(location2))` ?

Comment: Will try, altough now I realised that I am initilising point B as 0,0 therefore the initial distance of 42463 is the distance from my current location to the equater lol although its still off by 1500 km